# Screen inactive after closure of iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a page with a number of buttons which all call functions but only the exit button has a matching function. On loading of this page, a logon iFrame is launched and following a satisfactory logon, the iFrame asks the parent to remove it and my tests indicate it is removed but now the exit button won't work. My test for parent focus says it has focus. If I reload the page, I go back through the logon loop. Without the iFrame, the exit button works. The last things the iFrame child does is a window.parent.focus() command followed by a window.parent.closeLogon(). At closeLogon in the parent, it executes ifram.parentnode.removeChild(ifram). I have an event listener looking for “DOMNodeRemoved” and it responds in the positive. So, it appears that the child is gone and the parent has focus, so why doesn’t the exit button work?

Answer (score 0):

After much experimentation, I found that the form in question was sitting behind another form which was hidden. Re-ordering things in the HTML portion of the code solved that issue.